# Can I use different certifcates for www and Exchange?

Tags: tls, certificate, exchange

I have a website www.domainname.com and a published Exchange address of webmail.domainname.com The website is hosted offsite and the Exchange server is on-premises.

I need extended validation for the website but can get away with a single-domain level one certificate for Exchange. I would like to buy an EV certificate for the website and use a StartSSL certificate for the Exchange.

Would that work? Would that EV certificate not break autodiscover? How would Exchange know to use the StartSSL certificate and disregard the EV?

Comment: These are differnt hostnames hosted on different servers - so there is not more conflict between your two certificates as there is between your certificate and the certificate of security.stackexchange.com or gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

> Would that work?

If you setup EV certificate for web to first server and you setup StartSSL certificate to the second server, it will work. The servers will not care about the other one. There will be a problem only if you use HPKP.

> How would Exchange know to use the StartSSL certificate and disregard the EV?

Exchage server will not have the EV certificate installed, so it will not care about it.

> Would that EV certificate not break autodiscover?

It will not. Autodiscover is done at DNS level.